# Vector for arcs in path

Tags: linear-algebra, circles, vectors

I have path created from lines and arcs. I want to create next path inside or outside of this given path with given offset. For line I calculate line equation and it gives me simple perpendicular vector Ax+By+C=0 => v=[-B,A]. For arc I calculate vector from center point and point in the middle of arc. Then I normalize all vectors and multiply them by my given offset. This solution is not perfect because vector of arc sometimes goes inside sometimes outside of my path.  I always know direction of my lines and arcs - direction of my "move" on path.

[image: path]

Is there a way to calculate this vector different, better way or be sure that direction is OK.

Comment: It is not clear what you intend to do with the vectors you find. Do you "move" all points of the arc by the same distance and direction? Can you draw an example of what the "next" path should look like, superimposed on the original path you drew?

Comment: For arc I want to just move my center point and it moves my whole arc inside (my arc have center point, radius, start and end angle) I know than my line end point and arc start point will be in different positions but I will fix that later by finding intersection point or cutting line.

Comment: I have idea for better solution. I will calculate the arc vector from 2 neighbor vectors but what if I have 2 arc as neighbors

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot use the same arc center but a smaller or larger radius? That tends to produce more pleasing "next path" shapes.

Comment: I think I can use radius, this is maybe better soluction